# Can someone tell me why this recursive method with raw_input is not returning?

Tags: python, if-statement, recursion

Here is the statement:

```
def recursive(y):
    if y < 10:
        return y
    else:
        z = raw_input("Please enter a number: ")
        recursive(z)

x = raw_input("Please enter a number: ")
t = recursive(x)

print t
```

Whenever I run this, if I enter a number equal to or above 10, it prompts me to enter a number again. If I enter a number less than 10, it still tells me to enter a number; however, if I enter less than 10, shouldn't the `if y < 10` be true and it will return that number?

Comment: You aren't actually returning `recursive(z)`.  That line should be `return recursive(z)`.

Comment: returning `recursive(z)` still results in the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues:

- You do not return the result of your call
- You do not cast your raw_input (which is a string) as an int.

Here's the corrected version:

```
def recursive(y):
    if y < 10:
        return y
    else:
        z = raw_input("Please enter a number: ")
        return recursive(int(z))
```

Answer (score -1):

as always because you are nto returning in your else branch ...

```
def recursive(y):
    if float(y) < 10: # also you need to make this a number
        return y
    else:
        z = raw_input("Please enter a number: ")
        return recursive(z) #this is almost always the problem with these questions
```

Comment: That's *a* problem, but it keeps prompting him because he is comparing a string with an integer.

Comment: If I put `return recursive(z)`, the problem still persists

Comment: ahh fair point ... fixed (sort of... no error handling)